# Nested Matrix as field types

Tags: matrix

Are nested matrices panned for the coming future releases?

I currently have a matrix where users can upload various assets. For each asset, they should be able to specify different details but this cannot be achieved with the current features as there is no way in which the details could be related to a particular asset that has just been uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

I'll let Brandon and Brad answer regarding what's planned. :)

But, couldn't you solve this by adding fields to your assets? You can make fields of whatever type and add them to the field layout of asset sources. To edit them, you just double-click on the asset in the matrix. This works both for existing assets and newly uploaded assets as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have changed my configuration to link fields with the respective assets. But would still like to know if nested matrices are in the pipeline or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to Matrix within Matrix, then yes, it's on our radar, but we don't have an ETA for it.

Comment: +1 for nested matrix support :)

Comment: any update on this?